# How to Excel Copy from one Sheet to another with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help for my Excel sheet,
I have the first sheet and this is blank
and on the seconde sheet i have a list and in the column D i can change the value starts from 1. 
And when i changed in the column a cell then it should copy the row to the first sheet.

thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me what you want to do. If you want VBA to copy the row automatically, you should go to the module of the corresponding Worksheet in the VBA editor (in the list of the Wroksheets on the left, just double-click the Worksheet to open up the module associated with it). After that, write an event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(Target.Row).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(whichRowYouNeed)
    End If
End Sub
```

you should also write a routine to determine the 'whichRowYouNeed'
It may be the end of the filled range on Worksheet1

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry for my bad statement, i try it again :)

The first sheet is blank,

[The Second sheet is that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQTsP.jpg)

When i add a number in column D then I want to copy this row, in that case row 8, copy to the first sheet starting from row 5.

I hope now it is better to understand